# web scraping using python 2.7 AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'urlencode' for data=urllib.parse.urlencode(values)

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have been trying to extract data from websites and print it using python 2.7.13 on Windows 10.It gives me the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\Scripts\i1.py", line 5, in <module>
    data=urlparse.urlencode(values)
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'urlencode'
```

Here is the code:

```
    from urllib import urlopen
    from urlparse import urlparse
    url='http://pythonprogramming.net'
    values={'s':'basic','submit':'search'}
    data=urllib.parse.urlencode(values)
    data=data.encode('utf-8')
    req=urllib.request.Request(url,data)
    resp=urllib.request.urlopen(req)
    respData=resp.read()
    print(respData)
```

Since its Python 2 I have written `from urllib import urlopen` and `from urlparse import urlparse` instead of `import urllib.request` and `import urllib.parse`

Comment: Are you sure that your error is coming from this code. I don't see the line from error in the code you posted

Comment: You are messing up with the code. First read the urllib docs before starting.

Comment: You haven't imported urllib package try `import urllib` as first line in your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Solution 1

There is no parser object in the urllib module. You directly need to use urlopen with it and pass the url as the argument. Below is the modified and working piece of code:

```
import urllib
from urllib import urlopen

url='http://pythonprogramming.net'

values={'s':'basic','submit':'search'}
data=urllib.urlencode(values)
data=data.encode('utf-8')

response=urllib.urlopen(url,data)
responseData=response.read()

print responseData
```

### Solution 2

You can also use beautifulSoup library to scrape the data from your website. It's pretty easy to use. Below is the code pertaining to your example:

```
import urllib
from urllib import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url='http://pythonprogramming.net'

page = urllib.urlopen(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, "lxml")

print soup
```